# How to send a PUT request with wreq?

Tags: http, haskell, put, http-put, wreq

Here is how I would expect to be able to send a PUT request with `wreq`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Network.Wreq
main = put "http://httpbin.org/put" ["foo":=(1::Int)]
```

However, this gives the following error:

```
HttpExceptionRequest Request {
  host                 = "httpbin.org"
  port                 = 80
  secure               = False
  requestHeaders       = [("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"),("User-Agent","haskell wreq-0.5.3.2")]
  path                 = "/put"
  queryString          = ""
  method               = "POST"
  proxy                = Nothing
  rawBody              = False
  redirectCount        = 10
  responseTimeout      = ResponseTimeoutDefault
  requestVersion       = HTTP/1.1
}
 (StatusCodeException (Response {responseStatus = Status {statusCode = 405, statusMessage = "METHOD NOT ALLOWED"}, responseVersion = HTTP/1.1, responseHeaders = [("Date","Fri, 07 Feb 2020 19:26:28 GMT"),("Content-Type","text/html"),("Content-Length","178"),("Connection","keep-alive"),("Server","gunicorn/19.9.0"),("Allow","PUT, OPTIONS"),("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*"),("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials","true")], responseBody = (), responseCookieJar = CJ {expose = []}, responseClose' = ResponseClose}) "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN\">\n<title>405 Method Not Allowed</title>\n<h1>Method Not Allowed</h1>\n<p>The method is not allowed for the requested URL.</p>\n")
```

As is evident from the error message,
`wreq` appears to be sending a POST request instead,
despite the fact that I used the `put` method.

How can I get `wreq` to actually send a PUT request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the issue is that if you try to `put` using a `[FormParam]`, the method gets overridden and changed to `POST`.  If you `put` a different kind of payload:

```
main = put "http://httpbin.org/put" ("xyz" :: ByteString)
```

then it works fine:

```
Response {responseStatus = Status {statusCode = 200, statusMessage = "OK"}, ...
```

I believe this is a limitation/intentional design decision in the underlying `http-client` package that `wreq` uses. When the function [`urlEncodedBody`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-client-0.6.4/docs/Network-HTTP-Client.html#v:urlEncodedBody) is used to pack form data into the body, it has the side effect of changing the method of the request to `POST`.